# Connecting local psql db with web app inside the docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and know basic things. I have postgresql installed on my local Ubuntu server and i want to connect it with the web application which is inside of the docker container. What setting should I apply to allow that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your server's Public IP address for this instead of `localhost` in your docker container.

> Make sure that your firewall allows the port 5432

When you run an application on your local computer, the application can easily access all the services on your PC (i.e. localhost). When your application runs inside a Docker container it became a completely isolated environment from that machine (i.e. No access localhost and other system services unless you expose it directly) and can only use Host OS services directly served to Docker-Engine by Host OS. This is why you have to route through the Internet to access your service. Postgres in your case.

Comment: can you elaborate little more?

Comment: Modified Answer.

Comment: [in this](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/984434e5429c8a133038dad460c60295) `my docker-compose.yml` file i need to use my local postgres db. But in docker-compose we mentioned db as image. In this case it will create separate container right. And where i have to specify my db as localhost so that it can avoid creating separate container

Comment: If you want to use Postgres database on your local machine instead of running the inside the container, try replacing the host from `db` to your public IP address.

Comment: can you provide me the sample file. so that i can continue working on it.

Comment: In your config file, you are using postgres container which in your case is not required. You are trying to connect Postgres database on your own system. Try replacing the `DB_HOST` env variable to your public IP address and remove the `links` attribute and let us know the result.